# Meteor Blaze Subscription.ready() seems to trigger autorun.

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have now for umpteen months used [this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/) pattern for template level subscriptions in my Meteor/Blaze applications.

However, after upgrading to Meteor 1.4.3.2, I seem to have an odd bug on one of my templates.

I have this publication:

```
Meteor.publish('reports.byId', function(reportId){
  console.log("subscribe reports.byId", reportId);
  const reports = Reports.find({_id: reportId});
  console.log(reports.count());
  return reports;
});
```

I've removed any validation of user rights and have added the writes to check that I actually get data etc.

Now I'm calling this using this onCreated method:

```
Template.manageReport.onCreated(function(){
  const instance = this;
  const reportId = FlowRouter.getParam("reportId");
  instance.autorun(function(){
    const reportSub = instance.subscribe('reports.byId', reportId);
    if (reportSub.ready()){
      console.log("ready");
    }
  });
});
```

The odd thing is this: If I remove the check if the subscription is ready, everything works as expected. As soon as I check for the subscription readiness, the subscription is never ready and I can see via the log messages on the server that the subscriptions are requested to the tune of a few dozen times per second.

Comment: What was your Meteor version before you upgrade?

Comment: 1.3.x I believe. Sorry I did not actually have the .meteor folder under version control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `reportSub.ready()` is reactive so it does trigger the autorun. Actually it's the only thing triggering your autorun. When subscription is ready it triggers autorun and then it's not ready anymore, because you've just called it again. It's a loop.

I think you should not call `instance.subscribe` and check for its readiness all inside the same autorun.

Since `reportId` is a route parameter and it's not going to change, you don't need autorun for the subscription. You would only need it if any parameter were a reactive variable that could change.

This should work just fine. Let me know how it goes.

```
Template.manageReport.onCreated(function() {
  const instance = this;
  const reportId = FlowRouter.getParam("reportId");

  // Create subscription
  const reportSub = instance.subscribe('reports.byId', reportId);

  // Check when subscription is ready
  instance.autorun(function() {
    if (reportSub.ready()) {
      console.log("ready");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Okay. now the reason I had this in the first place, is that I have several references in the report that I want to create subscriptions to, that should run as soon as the report is available. I also don't understand why https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/ seems to work in loads of places that I have used it before.